# How to upload (not sync) files to iCloud Drive without using any browser?

Tags: mac, icloud, macos

I'm having a hard time with iCloud Drive on Mac. The files I drop in iCloud Drive folder simply sync while I wanted to upload the file to cloud so that I can delete the local copies in my Mac to free up space. I had to open iCloud in browser to upload files. As I'm on slow internet connection, uploads stops midway incase of large files. I thought optimised storage feature in macOS Sierra might solve the problem, but its automatic and I don't get to choose the files I actually want to upload. So I need suggestion about any third party apps that could upload files to cloud or any other cloud service that works seamlessly among apple products.

Comment: Have you tried Dropbox and Google Drive? (works seamlessly among apple products)

Comment: No doubt dropbox works fine but pricings are inflexible to me. Google photos fails to upload properly in my Mac unlike apple photos, which is fine.  So I'm left with icloud, syncing is perfect but I need more cloud functionality, so I can keep a backup of my files in cloud.@emotality

Comment: For me, iCloud is a pain.  The easiest and most convenient one I have found is [OneDrive from Microsoft](http://bit.ly/2a4bbWP).  it works on every device I have from OS X, iOS, Android, and Windows (even Linux).  For your sanity, stay away from iCloud.